# Capitalize first letter of first word in a every sentence in ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, railo, cfml

I want to get a string like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempor pulvinar enim! Nec aliquam massa faucibus sed?? Praesent nec consectetur sapien... Nulla dapibus rutrum turpis, ac porta erat posuere vel.

starting from string in all uppercase (or lowercase). For example:

> LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. DONEC TEMPOR PULVINAR ENIM! NEC ALIQUAM MASSA FAUCIBUS SED?? PRAESENT NEC CONSECTETUR SAPIEN... NULLA DAPIBUS RUTRUM TURPIS, AC PORTA ERAT POSUERE VEL.

How can I do?
Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code and specific errors/issues you are having.

Comment: [UpperFirst()](http://cflib.org/udf/upperFirst) might be helpful.

Comment: I had an answer but did not read carfully - sorry :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Take your text and set it to a variable like this:**

```
<cfset stringFixer = "LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. DONEC TEMPOR PULVINAR ENIM! NEC ALIQUAM MASSA FAUCIBUS SED?? PRAESENT NEC CONSECTETUR SAPIEN... NULLA DAPIBUS RUTRUM TURPIS, AC PORTA ERAT POSUERE VEL.">
```

**Lowercase everything:**

```
<cfset stringFixer = lCase(stringFixer)>
```

**Then you will need to match your string terminator with rematch like this:**

```
<cfset stringFixerBreaker = reMatch('\w.+?[.?]+',stringFixer)>
```

`reMatch()` will break apart your string into smaller discrete sentence strings...Then you could do a `replaceNoCase()` with left search for the first char then do the same with your replacement string which will be the same but we will throw a `uCase()` on that first character to capitalize it.

```
<cfloop array="#stringFixerBreaker#" index="i">
<cfoutput>#replaceNoCase(i,left(i, 1 ),uCase(left(i, 1 )))# </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

**Your output will look like this:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempor pulvinar enim! nec aliquam massa faucibus sed?? Praesent nec consectetur sapien... Nulla dapibus rutrum turpis, ac porta erat posuere vel.
```

***Edit:*** One last touch point to my answer.

**If you need to rebuild the string do this:**

```
<cfset str = "">

<cfloop array="#stringFixerBreaker#" index="i">
    <cfset str = str & replaceNoCase(i,left(i, 1 ),uCase(left(i, 1 ))) & " ">
</cfloop>
```

**Dump out the results to check everything is in order:**

```
<cfdump var="#str#">
```

Comment: You can also use, 1 ucase and rest lcase.
Like,

<cfset Str = listAppend(Str, ucase(left(idx,1)) & lcase(right(idx,Len(idx)-1))) />

Comment: Thanks Anit I have never seen it done like that.  I whipped this up really fast stepped through it like a process (I have a tendency to over think solutions to problems). I am going to test your expression.  I do like that CSS solution in the answer above but it doesn't fully solve the OPs problem.

Comment: @Frank Tudor OK. This is a great answer and I used this as the basis of a function. However, I found a vital improvement. If the last sentence of the text does not end in a period or a question mark, this entry will be omitted from the array. The following Regex guards against this flaw 

\w.+?[.?!]+|\w.+$

It also adds the third & final end of sentence punctuation mark, which is, of course an exclamation mark. 

This Regex will ensure that the last sentence is never missing, even, if the last sentence ends in an alpha numeric character. 

I have upvoted your answer anyway!

Answer (score 5):

I would use CSS rather than ColdFusion to do this

```
<span style="text-transform : capitalize"><cfoutput>#lcase(mystring)#</cfoutput></span>
```

Comment: Wait...There is a few steps missing, you need to lowercase the text before uppercasing the first letter Take his string as is and wrap that span around it (it doesn't lowercase all the other letters).  This also fails in title tags if you are required to force some data there for your page. This is nice (and handy) but doesn't satisfy the OPs requirements. I also did the capitalize javascript DOM as well...You need another few steps here. http://jsfiddle.net/franktudor/3nh27/

Comment: I have revised to cover the fact that the text comes in uppercase. I don't see anything about `<title>` tags in the OP

Comment: You are right ...he didn't. but my point about the title tag is this: we don't know what the OP wants to do with this functionality and the final fixed string.  But I have run into this one off problem first hand so I thought it was worth noting.

Answer (score 2):

While I personally like @James A Mohler solution, you can also do this in CF using a simple regex.

```
function Initcap(text){
    return rereplace(lcase(arguments.text), "(\b\w)", "\u\1", "all");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is by using regex and `ReReplace` or `ReReplaceNoCase`.

```
<cfset mystring = "lorem ipsum"/>

#ReReplace(mystring ,"\b(\w)","\u\1","ALL")#
```

Comment: @valueweaver - CF functions are not case sensitive, so it is doubtful that is why it was downvoted. It is probably because the above does actually not work. Plus, that approach [was already mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23821113/104223) several months back. The example in that thread does work. Note, their use of the `lower()` function.

Comment: @leigh I will run it again see why its not working. Can use ReReplaceNoCase.

Comment: @valueweaver - It is not the function. The logic is flawed. `\u` only converts the *first* letter of each word to upper case. What if the rest of the word is in upper case (like in the OP)? The code above won't handle that. Make sense?

Comment: So right. In a hurry to help someone in need forgot the basic testing of the logic ;)

Comment: Well, I am mot sure what the hurry was, as it was already answered six months ago ;-)

Comment: @Leigh The hurry was, not to go over all the answers and only seeing the question. Then saying to myself "oh I know this. I have faced this..let me help out" and typing out the code on HTC M8 while on a metro :)

Comment: Haha. Answering on cell phone is a certainly challenge, I will give you that :) But just a tip, you do not want to skip over existing answers (or testing, though good luck doing that on a cell phone ;-). [S.O. is different than a forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). The Q&A format is meant to be more streamlined. Duplicate questions and answers are discouraged, and tend to get deleted or down voted. It takes a little adjustment, but overall it is pretty good. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach and it works in all cases except in a situation such as mc'donald's. I can get it to capitalize the "d" but then the "s" would also be capitalized. Mc'Donald'S.

```
 <cfif ISDefined('mywds')>
   <cfoutput>
      #mywds#<br>
       <cfset catz = #LCase(mywds)#>
          <cfloop index="dogz" list="#catz#" delimiters=" ">
             <cfif Len(dogz) is 1 >
                 #UCase(dogz)#
             <cfelse>
                 #Left(UCase(dogz), 1 )##Right(LCase(dogz),
                 Len(dogz) - 1 )#
             </cfif>
          </cfloop>
      </cfoutput>
  </cfif>


 <cfform action="" method="POST" target="_self">
     <input type="text" name="mywds" size="50"><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </cfform>
```

This is a working form so you can paste in a .cfm page and it will function.

The 2nd cfif statement:

```
  <cfif Len(dogz) is 1 >
```

is so if someone enters text like "john t williams" the code will not throw an error on the single character "t".